# disk and network calculations, 1000 vs 1024

Tags: disk-usage

I have a .tar file that is 2.3TB as reported by `du -sh`

I want to reasonably calculate the time it will take to transfer over a 1gbps network where I routinely average 102 MB/sec.

Which is the correct math below, #1 or #2 ?

1. 2.3tb * 1000 * 1000 = 2300000 mb; divide by 102 MB/s = 22549 seconds = 6.26 hrs
2. 2.3tb * 1024 * 1024 = 2411724.8 mb; divide by 102 MB/s = 23644 seconds = 6.56 hs

Answer (score 1):

At least on my system (Debian 10), `man du` says the `-h` option will use powers of 1024 and you would have to use `--si` instead to get powers of 1000.

However, since data transfer speeds tend to use powers of 1000, and `du` is using 1024-based megabytes, you might have to go all the way to bytes to get the absolutely correct value:

2.3 TiB * (1024^4 bytes/TiB) / 102 000 000 bytes/s = 24973 seconds = 6.89 hrs